# sandboxed iframe seems to be sending cookies

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, sandbox

In this [example project](https://github.com/djfm/yt-recos-depersonalization-poc/tree/ff585d53cb84ba1e18bee05ab933e74d6c40de5d) I'm trying to get the YouTube recommendations **as if I was not logged in** and pass them to the normal page to do some stuff with them.

My approach was to include the YouTube video page in a sandboxed iframe and then pass the DOM of relevant elements with `postMessage` to the page that hosts the iframe for further processing and display.

Child / parent communication seems to be working, but if I'm logged in to YouTube on the parent page then the html passed back by `postMessage` by the iframe includes my YouTube user name so clearly it must have been access to cookies or something identifying me.

How come the page included in the sandboxed iframe can access my personal information?